# Put text in expanding div with onClick

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function expand(){
currentvalue = document.getElementById("test").value;
if(currentvalue == "off"){
 document.getElementById("test").value="on";
 document.getElementById("test").style.height="100px";
      
 var div = document.getElementById("test");
 var content = document.getElementById("test3");
      
 div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + content.innerHTML;
}
else{
 document.getElementById("test").value="off";
 document.getElementById("test").style.height="20px";
     
 var div = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "<div id='test2'><b>Div</b></div>";
      
}
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
 #test{
  position: absolute; 
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #CCCC00;
  height: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
 }
 #test2{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12pt;
 } 
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:expand()" value="on">
    <div id="test">
      <div id="test2"><b>Div</b></div>
    <div id="test3" style="display: none;">I want this to show up in my div!</div>
</div>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to make an expandable div container which will display some text inside of it 
when opened and then hide it when closed. I managed to make the div expand and close but 
I can't figure out how to make the text appear in the expanded box. I can do it by inserting the text in the javascript but I want it set as a variable so i can use the script for multiple pages with different text inside of the div.

I don't know if I've approached it the right way and would like some help, ty in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display your text just change the style of the `div` containing your text to `display: block`:

```
document.getElementById("test3").style.display = "block";
```

For your requirements, it would be something like this:

```
function expand() {
    if (currentValue == "off") {
        currentValue = "on";
        document.getElementById("test").style.height = "100px";
        document.getElementById("test3").style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        currentValue = "off";
        document.getElementById("test").style.height=  "20px";
        document.getElementById("test3").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3ycLhrom/) you have a working fiddle.